# ssl authentication for gcp kubernetes cluster is not working

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, cloud, containers

For an automation purpose, I have generated the kubernetes configuration file using the below API.

```
request = service.projects().zones().clusters()
          .get(projectId=project_id, zone=zone, clusterId=cluster_id)
```

The cluster is having both basic & ssl configurations enabled and only the basic authentication is working properly. When I changed the user context from admin to ca-user, I am getting the below error.

> Error from server (Forbidden): nodes is forbidden: User "client" cannot list nodes at the cluster scope: Unknown user "client"

The generated configuration file is given below.

```
apiVersion: v1
clusters:
- cluster:
    certificate-authority-data: *************
    server: https://*******
  name: gke_demo-205812_us-central1-a_cluster-1
contexts:
- context:
    cluster: gke_demo-205812_us-central1-a_cluster-1
    user: ca-user
  name: gke_demo-205812_us-central1-a_cluster-1
current-context: gke_demo-205812_us-central1-a_cluster-1
kind: Config
preferences: {}
users:
- name: admin
  user:
    password: *****************
    username: admin
- name: ca-user
  user:
    client-certificate-data: ******************
    client-key-data: ************************
```

Thanks in Advance. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try after running this command:

```
kubectl create clusterrolebinding client-admin \
    --clusterrole=cluster-admin \
    --user=client
```

You are giving cluster-admin permission to this user.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Is there any reason why Google is not providing cluster-admin role for SSL user but for basic auth user.?

Comment: can you clarify what you mean? Not sure if I understand your question.

Comment: Ok,  in the above configuration file I have created using the API, why the SSL user (client) and basic auth user (admin) are having different privileges. Both the users are created by GKE and what happens if I create a cluster with basic auth disabled.?

Comment: Because you probably have the user (admin) under your IAM, in your GCP console, as project owner, or editor, while user (client) has less privileges. Can you double check on this?